# ¿Cómo agregar una nueva fuente en ckeditor?

Tags: fuentes, ckeditor

Me gustaría saber como podría poner nuevas fuentes en ckeditor,he intentado configurando el config.js y font.css pero hasta el momento no lo logro,agradecería me explicaran.

Answer (score 0):

En ckeditor en la versión  4.5.4, se agrega al archivo config.js las siguientes lineas:
config.contentsCss = 'font.css';
El archivo font.css se agrega lo siguiente:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'fontNueva';
    src: url('/ruta/fuentes/nuevaFuente.otf?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
    url('/ruta/fuentes/nuevaFuente.otf') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
    url('/ruta/fuentes/nuevaFuente.otf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    url('/ruta/fuentes/nuevaFuente.otf#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */      
}
```

config.font_names = 'fontNueva;' + config.font_names;